# array_search not returning values

Tags: php

So I am writing this login script in php. I am choosing to not use a database like mysql so I am storing the usernames in one file and the hashes in another. Then it searches the username file and finds what line the username is on. Then it reads the same line in the hashes file and compares the user entered hash. For some reason it only works if the username is the last username in the file or the first. That means that $inFileUsernameKey does not have a value unless the username is the first or last. Here is my code:

```
    //Above is the code to get username and password from html forum and generate hash.
    $usernameFileHandle = fopen("passStuff/usernames.txt", "r+");
    $usernameFileContent = file_get_contents("passStuff/usernames.txt");
    $usernameFileContent = explode("\n", $usernameFileContent);
    //Using fopen() and fclose b/c at some point I will be adding in a account creation section
    fclose($usernameFileHandle);

    $hashFileHandle = fopen("passStuff/hash.txt", "r+");
    $hashFileContent = file_get_contents("passStuff/hash.txt");
    $hashFileContent = explode("\n", $hashFileContent);
    //Using fopen() and fclose b/c at some point I will be adding in a account creation section
    fclose($hashFileHandle);

    $inFileUsernameKey = array_search($username, $usernameFileContent);
    $inFileUsername = $usernameFileContent[$inFileUsernameKey];
    $i = 0;
    echo "usernameFileContent: <br>";
    while($i < count($usernameFileContent)){
        echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp", $i, ": ", $usernameFileContent[$i], "<br>";
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $i = 0;
    echo "hashFileContent: <br>";
    while($i < count($hashFileContent)){
        echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp", $i, ": ", $hashFileContent[$i], "<br>";
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    echo "In File Username: ", $inFileUsername;
    $inFilePassword = $hashFileContent[$inFileUsernameKey];
    $inFilePassword = trim($inFilePassword);
    echo "<br>Username Key: ", $inFileUsernameKey;
    echo "<br>In File Hash: ", $inFilePassword;
    echo "<br><br>Login: ";
    if(strcmp($inFilePassword, $loginInputHash) == 0){
        echo "<div style='color: #0DFF00'>Accepted</div>";
    }
    if(strcmp($inFilePassword, $loginInputHash) != 0){
        echo "<div style='color: #FF0000'>Denied</div>";
        echo "STRCMP COMPARE: ", strcmp($inFilePassword, $loginInputHash);
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working? Excuse my php noob-ness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fopen()` is not needed before `file_get_contents()` and indeed if you are reading a linewise array, you don't need `file_get_contents() + explode()` either. There's simply [`file()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: Can you post an example of the contents of the username file?

Comment: May I ask the reasoning for storing them in separate files? Why not just `user hash` in one file? Seems like an awful lot of added complexity and possibility for failure/out of sync passwords for no security gain.

Comment: I just noticed the comments in there about fopen()/fclose().  Don't expend the effort, and use `file_put_contents()` instead.

Comment: @Daniel Paul Searles A sample of the user file is "bob" new line "joe" new line, ect.

Comment: Use `print_r($usernameFileContent);` and `print_r($username)` to check values. Maybe usernames in file have extra char (for example space at the end) or `$username` has some extra char.